# "mailx -a x.txt ..." hangs, while "cat x.txt | mailx..." works

Tags: postfix, mutt, smtp, mailx

As described in the subject, `mailx -a somefile.txt -s "blah blah" myaddress@bigcorp.com` hangs, while emails sent via `cat somefile.txt | mailx -s "blah blah" myaddress@bigcorp.com` arrive.

The `/etc/postfix/main.cf` `relayhost` variable is set to our corporate mail server.

In a certainly related note, mail sent via mutt (with smtp_url pointing to the same corporate mail server as the postfix relayhost) seemingly disappears into the bit bucket.

```
echo "" | mutt -s "this is a test" myaddress@bigcorp.com
```

This all was working perfectly until late last month.  None of the files in `/etc/postfix` have changed in 2+ years, so I wonder if the mail server was reconfigured.

Comment: Does `/var/log/mail.log` on the server shows anything coming from the client? How do you invoke `mutt`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `maillog` doesn't say anything.  `mail.log` does not exist.  Question edited to show mutt command.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> mailx -a somefile.txt -s "blah blah" myaddress@bigcorp.com
> ```

Doesn't hang, it's waiting for you to enter the body of the email on its stdin.

If it didn't hang before, maybe it was because stdin was opened on `/dev/null` in which case you would have gotten an empty email body.

> ```
> cat somefile.txt | mailx -s "blah blah" myaddress@bigcorp.com
> ```

A weird way to write:

```
<somefile.txt mailx -s "blah blah" myaddress@bigcorp.com
```

Gets the body of the email from the file and adds no attachment.

You could also do:

```
echo please find the file attached. |
  mailx -a somefile.txt -s "blah blah" myaddress@bigcorp.com
```

Comment: `<somefile.txt mailx` is weird.  The purpose of `cat somefile.txt | mailx` is obvious to any rank newbie.

Comment: And the mutt problem?

Comment: @RonJohn then `mailx ... <somefile.txt` - the purpose of that should be equally, if not more, obvious as compared to the all the extra stuff in `cat somefile.txt | mailx`

Comment: @muru we each have our own preference.  You think it's a useless use of `cat` while I think it's a clear demonstration of pipelining from one program to another.

Comment: @RonJohn, `grep '^' file | cat - /dev/null | paste | cut -c1- | sed -n p | tr x x | mailx...` is also a demonstration of pipelining with an usage of `cat`  making a little more sense (as it con`cat`enates more than one file) but I'm not sure I see how it's relevant.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas surely you know that pipelining is great for iteratively building one task upon another.  Maybe someone builds a process which you described, but I'm dubious.